# Is there a way to dynamically reorder the list of parameters in Crystal Reports XI?

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

The enterprise software I use (Dynamics GP with Forms Printer) requires crystal report parameters to be in a specific order.  Live documents have one set of parameters and historical documents have another completely different set.  Instead of writing and maintaining two separate reports I'd like to create one crystal report that contains all of the parameters.  Unfortunately due to the restrictions on the order of the parameters I haven't had any success.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

The report's parameters are accessible via the ReportDocument.DataDefinition.[ParameterFieldDefinitions Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691378%28v=vs.71%29).  It is derived from the abstract [SCRCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226094%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  The SCRCollection Class implements the [ICollection Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx).

Perhaps you can copy the individual ParameterFieldDefintions to a temporary Collection or ArrayList, order them as desired, clear the ParameterFieldDefinitions, then restore the items from the temporary collection.

Comment: Hi Craig, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to me.  I'll dive in to the classes you suggest and see what I can find.